# Crash when using boost::iostreams

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, boost-iostreams, compression

I'm trying to use boost::iostreams(1.53.0) to uncompress a HTTP request body and later process it.
But I get a crash when I run the following code.

```
try {
    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    ifstream file(argv[1], std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
    in.push(gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    std::stringstream strstream;
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, strstream);
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

The crash occurs in `gzip_decompressor()`, more specifically in `gzip_header() { reset(); }` from boost's gzip.hpp (by looking at the call stack).

I have compiled myself the boost::iostreams library and also tried to use boost from macports, but the same crash occurs. I also tried using the [gzstream library](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/), but that crashes also in a constructor, more specifically in the constructor of `igzstream`.

I tend to believe that this is a zlib-related problem.
I didn't specify, I'm using a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion and xCode 4.6 to build and run the code.

Did any of you encounter such a problem before?

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and post a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the argv[1] actually points to a file?

Comment: @Zac The gzip_decompressor() crashing has nothing to do with the argv supplied. Nevertheless, it points to a correct file path.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: Apple's LLVM compiler.
I was sure I was using GCC, but it seems I wasn't.

I discovered this by stumbling upon another weird crash, which happened just by instantiating a `std::string` object. This made me check the project settings, where I found I was using the LLVM compiler, which probably wasn't happy with me linking gcc-built libraries.

Thanks for your replies.